# Create Outlook calendar event with Visual Basic VB for selected chosen calendar, when having multiple accounts

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I want to create a calendar event/invitation.
Script is working, when only one account is registered in Outlook, and *event* is created for this single calendar (account).

I have two accounts registered in Outlook. One of the accounts is company-managed (let's call it *FIRST*). I have also manually created account (let's call it *SECOND*).

The problem occurs when I want to create an *event* "on behalf" of *SECOND* calendar.
I set *SECOND* account as primary account in Outlook with:
Outlook->File->Account Settings->Account Setting...->Email Tab->Set as default.

When using (almost) identical code as below to create Outlook **email** object, script is working, and field "Sender" in the message is populated with **correct** *SECOND* account name.
[image: Picture: Email outlook object created, with SENDER populated with correct SECOND account]

I tried to set property: `objAppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount = myAccount`, with the *SECOND* account, but then *Sender* field is left empty, and **you can't select account from combo**.
When I send it anyway, it is sent to correct recipients, but not sent to my SECOND calendar (desired), and invitation/event is visible in my FIRST calendar, which I don't want to use anymore.
[image: Picture: Outlook event object with FROM field empty, no selection possible]

When I'm **not** setting property: `objAppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount = myAccount`, *event* object is created, but is assigned with *FIRST* account, despite *SECOND* is set as default.
[image: Picture: Event created with wrong sender, and NO SELECTION possible for SECOND account]

When I create an invitation with a double-click on SECOND account calendar, then the invitation is created with correct *SECOND* account populated in SENDER field, (still no option to select other account - but no need, as is correct).

```vb
Sub OutOfOfficeEvent()

    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim myAccount As Outlook.Account

    'try to find PERSONAL account. If failed, then send with last avail on the list Application.Session.Accounts
    For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
        Set myAccount = oAccount
        If InStr(UCase(oAccount.DisplayName), "PERSONAL.COM") Then
          Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim objOutlookApplication As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objRecipient As Recipient
    Dim objRecipients As Recipients
    
    Set objOutlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objAppointmentItem = objOutlookApplication.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    '###############################################
    '#######  NOT working for event/invitation 
    '#######  Working OK for email object creation
    '###############################################
    objAppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount = myAccount
    '###############################################
    
    
    objAppointmentItem.Display
    Set objRecipients = objAppointmentItem.Recipients
    
    Set objRecipient = objAppointmentItem.Recipients.Add("somebody1@PERSONAL.COM")
    Set objRecipient = objAppointmentItem.Recipients.Add("somebody2@PERSONAL.COM")
    objRecipient.Type = olRequired
    
    For Each objRecipient In objAppointmentItem.Recipients
        objRecipient.Resolve
    Next
    
    Dim DateStart As Date
    Dim DateEnd   As Date
    
    DateStart = DateTime.DateAdd("d", 0, DateTime.DateAdd("h", 1, DateTime.DateAdd("s", -Second(Now()), DateTime.DateAdd("n", -Minute(Now()), Now()))))
    DateEnd = DateTime.DateAdd("h", 1, DateStart)
    
    With objAppointmentItem
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .Subject = "[OOO] " & strUser
        .Start = DateStart
        .End = DateEnd
        .AllDayEvent = False
        .ReminderSet = False
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .ResponseRequested = False
        .Location = ""
        .Body = "Some body content"
    End With
    
    objAppointmentItem.Display
    Set objOutlookApplication = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just found solution using title of my post :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736236/create-outlook-appointment-in-specific-calendar-from-excel

Comment: The link mentions shared calendars, not second accounts configured in Outlook. You need to use a bit another approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of creating new items in Outlook. See [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) for more information.

If you have two accounts configured in Outlook you need to get the right calendar folder and then add a new calendar entry there. To get this done you can use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Store` class which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile. So, you may get the right store and add the new calendar entry.

The [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property returns a Stores collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile.

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oCalendar As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oCalendar = oStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
 
   Debug.Print (oCalendar.FolderPath) 
 
 Next 
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and with above suggestion and some more Google, I found the total solution:

```
Dim myAI As Outlook.AppointmentItem
myAI = Nothing
Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
For Each oStore In colStores
    Dim oCalendar As Outlook.Folder
    Set oCalendar = oStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
    If LCase(oCalendar.Description) = "<accountname>" Then
        Set myAI = oCalendar.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```